# Import from text file trim and export to CSV powershell

Tags: powershell

I've currently been assigned the task of finding out what desktops a user has logged onto in our system.  I'm fairly new to Powershell so I apologize for the very long post and messy script

There is a logon script that places this information into a log file whenever a user logs on.  As shown below.

```
Script started: 1/01/2010 00:00:00

Information : Script Ver:       1.05
Information : LOGONSERVER:      %servername%
Information : USERNAME:         %username%
Information : COMPUTERNAME:     %computername%
Information : COMPUTER SITE:    $location%
Information : OS Version:       %system%
Information : Domain:           %domain%
```

I need to obtain both "Script started: 1/01/2010 00:00:00" and "Information : COMPUTERNAME:     %computername%" and then export these parts into a CSV file.  I can get the information out using

```
$Str ComputerName = Get-Content -Path %log%| Select-String "COMPUTERNAME:"
```

For Multiple users, this only gives me the last computer logged onto an not all the desktops from the log file.  Is there are way to get all the computer names and Script Started and export them into a CSV file in separate columns?  And maybe a simpler and shorter way.

```
Foreach ($ObjCSVline in $(Import-csv "\\tgfilp05\hdact\DFP\Nat\Scripts\LastLogon\LastLogon.csv"))
{
$strUsername = $ObjCSVline.Lastlogon

try {
$arrUserIdOutput = Get-ADUser $strUsername -Properties homedirectory | select *
} catch {
Write-Host "User: " $strUsername" Does not exist"
}

$strUserHomeDirectory = $arrUserIdOutput.HomeDirectory
$strUserLogs = $strUserHomeDirectory + $strLogFile

if ((Test-Path $strUserLogs) -eq $true) {

    $strLogs = Get-Content $strUserLogs | Select-String "Script started:        " | Select-Object -Last 1

    $Time = $strLogs -replace "Script started:      ","" 

    $StrComp = Get-Content $strUserLogs | Select-String "Information : COMPUTERNAME:    " | Select-Object -Last 1

    $computerID = $StrComp -replace "Information : COMPUTERNAME:    ",""

} else { $strUserLogs = $strUserLogs + $strOldLogFile
    if ((Test-Path $strUserLogs) -eq $true) {

    $strLogs = Get-Content $strUserLogs | Select-String "Script started: " | Select-Object -Last 1

    $Time = $strLogs -replace "Script started: ",""
    } else 
    {
    Write-Host "unable to find log file for" $strUsername
    }
    }

$objOutput.desktop = $computerID
$objOutput.TimeOutput = $Time
$objOutput.Username = $strUsername
$objOutput | Select-Object Username,TimeOutput,desktop | Export-Csv "\\tgfilp05\hdact\DFP\Nat\Scripts\LastLogon\LastLogonDetails.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: I can't help but think this is better logged & queried in a different manner altogether. Can't Active Directory log when people log in, and from where? Then you would query that log, instead of parsing a text file.

Answer (score 0):

So, given that log file's format I would suggest using a RegEx match for either "Script Started" or "Information: COMPUTERNAME:" or "Information: USERNAME:". Then for each match I'd run that match through a Switch to assign the result to the appropriate variable for $LoginDate, $UserName, or $ComputerName. After the Switch is done I check to see if we have all 3 items recorded, and if so output a custom object containing the three properties, and clear the variables to setup for the next login record. This will do that:

```
GC $strUserLogs|?{$_ -match "(Script started:\s*?|Information.+?: COMPUTERNAME:.\s*?|Information.+?: USERNAME:.\s*?)(\w.*)"}|%{
    Switch($Matches[1]){
        {$Matches[1] -like "Script Started*"}{$LoginDate = $Matches[2]}
        {$Matches[1] -like "*USERNAME*"}{$UserName = $Matches[2]}
        {$Matches[1] -like "*COMPUTERNAME*"}{$ComputerName = $Matches[2]}
    }
    If($LoginDate -and $UserName -and $ComputerName){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Login Date"=$LoginDate
            "Computer Name"=$ComputerName
            "User Name"=$UserName
        }
    Remove-Variable LoginDate,ComputerName,UserName
    }
}|Sort "User Name","Login Date"|Export-CSV "\\tgfilp05\hdact\DFP\Nat\Scripts\LastLogon\LastLogonDetails.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

At the end I sort by user, and by date, and export to the log file you had in your example. Without exporting to CSV and just letting it output to screen I parsed a test log file:

```
Script started: 1/01/2010 00:00:00

Information : Script Ver:       1.05
Information : LOGONSERVER:      %servername%
Information : USERNAME:         JimBob
Information : COMPUTERNAME:     DesktopA
Information : COMPUTER SITE:    $location%
Information : OS Version:       %system%
Information : Domain:           %domain%
Script started: 1/02/2010 00:00:00

Information : Script Ver:       1.05
Information : LOGONSERVER:      %servername%
Information : USERNAME:         MarySue
Information : COMPUTERNAME:     LaptopB
Information : COMPUTER SITE:    $location%
Information : OS Version:       %system%
Information : Domain:           %domain%
Script started: 1/03/2010 00:00:00

Information : Script Ver:       1.05
Information : LOGONSERVER:      %servername%
Information : USERNAME:         JimBob
Information : COMPUTERNAME:     ServerC
Information : COMPUTER SITE:    $location%
Information : OS Version:       %system%
Information : Domain:           %domain%
```

And it output it nicely:

```
Login Date                        Computer Name                     User Name                       
----------                        -------------                     ---------                       
1/01/2010 00:00:00                ServerC                           JimBob                          
1/03/2010 00:00:00                LaptopB                           JimBob                          
1/02/2010 00:00:00                DesktopA                          MarySue
```

Comment: Thanks!  Will have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks heaps TheMadTechnician.